# Default fontFamily in React Native when it is not declared

Tags: react-native

If one does not define the fontFamily prop for a Text component, which one is used in iOS and Android. I have read numerous posts about this, but they all talk about HOW to specify one in fontFamily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It defaults to the system font defined on the phone. This is accomplished by a virtual font called `System` that was added a long time ago (check out issue [#1611](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1611) and the linked commits). So there is no one catchall answer as OSes can decided to change this over time (ex: iOS 9 switching to San Francisco), and users on Android can even change it themselves.

At the moment, iOS 9+ defaults to San Francisco while most Android phones default to Roboto.